# Schedule a task for events

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want to schedule a once time task, why and what is the case:

The Case
I have an game with more than one event, for example a card game with 3 matches, each 'match' has the user to win 2 of the 3 games to win the event.

Match 1 best of 3 games
Match 2 best of 3 games
Match 3 best of 3 games

Now I would like to start each match every 3 minutes and each game will take 1 minute, for example

Hour - Game

1. 00:00 Start Match 1 and start Game 1 of Match 1
2. 00:01 End Game 1 of Match 1
3. 00:01 Start Game 2 of Match 1
4. 00:02 End Game 2 of Match 1
5. 00:02 Start Game 3 of Match 1
6. 00:03 End Game 3 of Match 1
7. 00:03 End Match 1

Ofcourse every task has only to start once and will never ever happen again (it will happen again, but not with the same players/game ID/match ID)

So what I think I should do is to create a Match Taskwith a runable and that runable will create a Task for each game. After the game Task is finished I should shutdown that thread or is there something else how you can start something like the case above?

I had already read alot about the Timer en ScheduledExecutorService class, but which one of these is the best of is there another better example?

Thanks for your time!

edit:

Ofcourse always after you asked a question, you find some things. So I will post my class here, this is not the dynamic class, but a test class. The Runable runs now when I want it, the only question I have is, when the runable is executed and finished will he be removed from the thread. Or will the thread pull get full after 100.000.000 events of these?

```
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;

 import com.ibm.icu.util.GregorianCalendar;

 public class TaskScheduler {

public static GregorianCalendar result = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 5, 15, 54, 0);
public static GregorianCalendar resulta = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 5, 15, 55, 00);

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    System.out.println("First thing: " + result.getTime());
    System.out.println("second thing: " + resulta.getTime());


    createNewTimerTask(1);
    createNewTimerTask(21);
    createNewTimerTask(31);
    createNewTimerTask(41);
    createNewTimerTask(51);
    createNewTimerTask(61);
    createNewTimerTask(71);
    createNewTimerTask(81);
    createNewTimerTask(91);
    createNewTimerTask(01);
    createNewTimerTask(111);
    createNewTimerTask(122);
    createNewTimerTask(133);
    createNewTimerTask(144);
    createNewTimerTask(155);
    createNewTimerTask(166);
    createNewTimerTask(177);
}

private static void createNewTimerTask(int id) {
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new Test(id), resulta.getTime());
}
 }



 class Test extends TimerTask {
public static GregorianCalendar result = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 5, 15, 52, 0);
private int id;

Test(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000l);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("ID: " + id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the timer task terminates it will be garbage collected. After 100 000 000 events, creating another timer task will run normally.